# Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -wrong classpath maybe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I receive the above error when running mvn spring-boot:run
more specific [mvn spring-boot:run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4eRH.png)
after some research i found out that i have to specify the main class inside pom like this [pom property-start-class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3EgP.png) the path of my mainclass is:[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzr5z.png)
and i still get this error:[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHGds.png)
am i doing something wrong with the classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run this command from the root project:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with `mvn spring-boot:run`

However if you are getting an error, just run  `mvn clean install` first